# How to show something under a particular situation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have so far done this:

```
<form>
Select image:
<select id="artwork">
  <option>image 1</option>
  <option>image 2</option>
  <option>image 3</option>
  <option>image 4</option>
  <option>image 5</option>
</select>
<input id="turnin" class="turnin" type="button" value="Upload" onclick="start()">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
function start()
{
var select=document.getElementById('artwork');
var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;


  $('#blah').prepend('<img id="image_2" src="image2.jpg" />');  

};
    //-->
</script>
```

However, i want the

```
$('#blah').prepend('<img id="image_2" src="image2.jpg" />');
```

part to take effect only when the option was "image 2". is there a way to do this?

EDIT: it would be also helpful if there is a way so that the button works only once.

Comment: That would be an `if` statement, one of the most basic things in JavaScript... Why are you using jQuery if you can't even do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function start() {
    var select = document.getElementById('artwork');

    if($(select).val() === 'image 2') {
        $('#blah').prepend('<img id="image_2" src="image2.jpg" />');  
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all, thx. it worked. is there a way so that the button works only once? cause right now, if i click it twice, the picture shows up 2 times.

Comment: so you want your button to be disabled after first click

Comment: wait. sorry. nevermind. i figured it out somehow. thx anyways.

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
$('#artwork').on('change',function(){
if($(this).value=='image 2'){
    $('#blah').prepend('<img id="image_2" src="image2.jpg" />');
}});
```

you can add else in this and handle other cases

Answer (score 0):

Note that the jQuery library is referenced / loaded in the `<head>`

This answer does not need the user to press the Upload button... It watches for a change in the value of the `select` control.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#artwork').change(function() {
                    var sel = $(this).val();
                    if (sel == "image 2")
                        $('#blah').prepend('<img id="image_2" src="image2.jpg" />'); 
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <form>
    Select image:
    <select id="artwork">
      <option>image 1</option>
      <option>image 2</option>
      <option>image 3</option>
      <option>image 4</option>
      <option>image 5</option>
    </select>
    <input id="turnin" class="turnin" type="button" value="Upload">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

However, if you want the Upload button to trigger the operation, modify it thus:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#turnin').click(function() {
                    var sel = $(this).val();
                    if (sel == "image 2")
                        $('#blah').prepend('<img id="image_2" src="image2.jpg" />'); 
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <form>
    Select image:
    <select id="artwork">
      <option>image 1</option>
      <option>image 2</option>
      <option>image 3</option>
      <option>image 4</option>
      <option>image 5</option>
    </select>
    <input id="turnin" class="turnin" type="button" value="Upload">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```